# why isn't CreateProcessW() performing the Command provided?

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

To present the minimal reproducible code I wrote a code to delete a file from a given location using CreateProcessW(). The file does not get deleted. Some help would be really useful in knowing why this isn't working.

```
dprintf(("Error %d", GetLastError()));
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO), 0 };
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
LPWSTR AppName = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
string bstr = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del"+trans_loc+"a.rtf";
LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[bstr.length()];
int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, Command, wchars_num);
DWORD res = CreateProcessW(AppName, Command, 0, 0, 0, DETACHED_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

define TRANSCRIPT_LOCATION "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\" this is the location of the file to be deleted

GetLastError() keeps returning 50(ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED) and the value of res = 1

Comment: Did you look at GetLastError()? Did you debug this at all?

Comment: Yes, it keeps giving 50 (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED).

Comment: It is not obvious why you want to run cmd.exe when you actually want to execute gcloud.  Temporarily use /k instead of /c so you can see error messages.  Could be as simple as the file path needing double-quotes.  And fix the error handling, GetLastError() is only valid if CreateProcess returns FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is that

```
LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[bstr.length()];
```

is not right. Perhaps

```
LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[bstr.length() + 1];
```

will work. A better alternative is to use `wchars_num` for allocating memory.

instead of

```
LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[bstr.length()];
int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, Command, wchars_num);
DWORD res = CreateProcessW(AppName, Command, 0, 0, 0, DETACHED_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

use

```
int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0);
LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[wchars_num];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), -1, Command, wchars_num);
DWORD res = CreateProcessW(AppName, Command, 0, 0, 0, DETACHED_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

---

A second issue is that perhaps you missed a space character when composing the `del` command.

```
string bstr = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del " + trans_loc + "a.rtf";
//                                                  ^^
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the change. But the issue still persists

Comment: Okay, adding the space after "del" command did the trick. Thanks a lot. I have edited the question a little to go back to my original problem (del was just for the minimal reproducible example).

Comment: bstr is the command to run gcloud and recieve output in a textfile. Only the textfile is created. the gcloud prompt never comes up.

Comment: @PrafulSrivastava Changing the question so that the answer doesn't fit anymore isn't good. You should have left your original question as it was and accepted this answer and then asked a new question. You can revert to an earlier version if you click the [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60731093/revisions) link.

Comment: oh okay. I'll ask a new question and re-edit this one.

Answer (score 1):

I see a number of problems with your code:

- `LPWSTR AppName = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";` does not compile in C++11 and later. You need to (and *should*) use `LPCWSTR` instead, since a string literal is `const` data, and `LPCWSTR` is a pointer to `const` WCHAR data,  but `LPWSTR` is a pointer to non-`const` WCHAR data.
- In `string bstr = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del"+trans_loc+"a.rtf";`, you are missing a required space character between the `del` command and the filename to delete.
- In `LPWSTR Command = new WCHAR[bstr.length()];`, you are not allocating enough space for a null terminator.  Also, you should not be using `bstr.length()` for the converted length anyway, because there is no guarantee that the converted string will not be larger than the original string.  You should call `MultiByteToWideChar()` one time with a `NULL` output buffer to calculate the actual converted length (which you ARE doing), THEN allocate the memory (which you are NOT doing - you are allocating too soon!), THEN call `MultiByteToWideChar()` again to do the actual conversion.
- You are leaking the allocated memory (you are not calling `delete[] Command;`). I would suggest using `std::wstring` or `std::vector<WCHAR>` instead of `new WCHAR[]`.
- You say that `res` is being set to 1, which means `CreateProcessW()` is actually *successful* in running `cmd.exe` (now, whether `cmd.exe` is successful in executing your command is a different matter - use [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) to find that out), and thus the return value of `GetLastError()` is *meaningless*!  It is certainly meaningful to call `GetLastError()` *before* calling `CreateProcessW()`
- You are calling `WaitForSingleObject()` regardless of whether `CreateProcessW()` succeeds or fails.

Try this instead:

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

std::string bstr = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del \"" + trans_loc + "a.rtf\"";

int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), bstr.length(), NULL, 0);
if (wchars_num == 0)
{
    dprintf(("MultiByteToWideChar Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
else
{
    std::vector<WCHAR> Command(wchars_num + 1);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), bstr.length(), Command.data(), wchars_num);

    if (!CreateProcessW(nullptr, Command.data(), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
    {
        dprintf(("CreateProcessW Error %d", GetLastError()));
    }
    else
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
        GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
        dprintf(("cmd.exe Exit Code %d", dwExitCode));

        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using Windows 10 build 17035 or later and have enabled the "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" option in your Windows settings (or, if `trans_loc` does not contain any non-ASCII, non-user-locale characters), then no `MultiByteToWideChar()` conversion is needed at all:

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

std::string Command = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del \"" + trans_loc + "a.rtf\"";

if (!CreateProcessA(nullptr, const_cast<char*>(Command.c_str()), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
{
    dprintf(("CreateProcessA Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
else
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
    dprintf(("cmd.exe Exit Code %d", dwExitCode));

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

That being said, a better option would be to simply use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` to begin with:

```cpp
STARTUPINFO si = {};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};

// make sure trans_loc is std::wstring instead of std::string...
std::wstring bstr = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /C del \"" + trans_loc + L"a.rtf\"";

if (!CreateProcessW(nullptr, Command.data(), nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, DETACHED_PROCESS, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi))
{
    dprintf(("CreateProcessW Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
else
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);
    dprintf(("cmd.exe Exit Code %d", dwExitCode));

    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
}
```

Of course, the simplest solution would be to just not use `cmd.exe / C del` at all, but instead use [`DeleteFileW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew):

```cpp
// make sure trans_loc is std::wstring instead of std::string...
std::wstring bstr = trans_loc + L"a.rtf";

if (!DeleteFileW(bstr.c_str()))
{
    dprintf(("DeleteFileW Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
```

Or, if you insist on using a UTF-8 encoded `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string bstr = trans_loc + "a.rtf";

int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), bstr.length(), NULL, 0);
if (wchars_num == 0)
{
    dprintf(("MultiByteToWideChar Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
else
{
    std::vector<WCHAR> wstr(wchars_num + 1);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bstr.c_str(), bstr.length(), wstr.data(), wchars_num);

    if (!DeleteFileW(wstr.c_str()))
    {
        dprintf(("DeleteFileW Error %d", GetLastError()));
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using Windows 10 with UTF-8 support enabled (or, if `trans_loc` does not contain any non-ASCII, non-user-locale characters):

```cpp
std::string bstr = trans_loc + "a.rtf";

if (!DeleteFileA(bstr.c_str()))
{
    dprintf(("DeleteFileA Error %d", GetLastError()));
}
```

Comment: In addition to all that, `bstr` is a terrible name for something that's not a Windows BSTR.